# ZfcRbac Role Provider and Identity getRoles()

Tags: zend-framework2, identity, roleprovider, rbac, zfc-rbac

I couldn't understand a concept when using [`ZfcRbac`](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/zfc-rbac).

**1.** I use my own `User` entity with implementing `ZfcRbac\Identity\IdentityInterface`

**2.** This interface has `addRole` and `getRoles` methods and `getRoles()` should return array of `Rbac\Role\RoleInterface` so I have an array of `Rbac\Role\RoleInterface`

**3.** I get roles from my custom model and add roles to `User` entity via `addRole()` when authenticating the user

**4.** `Rbac\Role\RoleInterface` has `hasPermission()` method which returns role's permissions

Summary:
After authentication I have my authenticated `User` identity information, roles and permissions for per role. Why  I need another `RoleProvider` and list my all roles in it? What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [in the php doc in the `IdentityInterface`](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/zfc-rbac/blob/master/src/ZfcRbac/Identity/IdentityInterface.php#L32) The `getRoles()` method can return two things:

**1.** an array of strings

**2.** an array of `Rbac\Role\RoleInterface`

In case you return an array of strings you need an additional `RoleProvider` to "translate" the strings to actual instances of a `Rbac\Role\RoleInterface`. If you return an array of `Rbac\Role\RoleInterface` it seems to me that you do not longer need a `RoleProvider`.

Comment: Thanks lot for your answer, I decided to keep my RoleProvider inside User entitiy. So I won't use a role_provider, but if you don't set any role_provider zfcrbac gives 'No role provider has been set for ZfcRbac' error. How can I handle this.

Comment: Not sure... Maybe you can still set a `ObjectRepositoryRoleProvider` that points to your doctrine `Role` entity like mentioned [here in the docs](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/zfc-rbac/blob/master/docs/03.%20Role%20providers.md#objectrepositoryroleprovider). In the end I think it won't be used if your indentity holds `RoleInterface`, but at least it is pointing to the correct source.

Comment: I tried this 'role_provider' => [
            'ZfcRbac\Role\InMemoryRoleProvider' => [
                '' => [],
            ]
        ], And worked :)

Comment: I think it is better to make sure that the `RoleProvider` you specify ends up returning the list of roles that you are actually using in your identities. It is more consistent...

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that Role Providers are not for generating a user role list, but rather to the load and build an accessible listing of application roles with permissions to be used during and in the authorization service.

So I am extending the `Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService` so I can implement the abstract method `getRoles()` of the `ZfcRbac\Identity\IdentityInterface`.

I still need to code for the accessing of user roles and storage of user roles to be authorized. There are not many examples of loading user roles using the `AuthenticationService` or `IdentityInterface`, and the loading of the role provider seems well documented. I am trying to decouple Authentication from Authorization.  I Authenticate and then I load the user's role in my Authorization module because I may have cases where authentication is all that is necessary and the loading of a guest role is overhead.